# Change Domain Name ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I hosted my website in Azure with student account. How to change my domain name like [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)

I tried many variants but thet do not works. Any ideas? I watched a lof of videos in Yotube but they don't help. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to purchase a domain name, then point it to the public IP address of the server hosting your application using a "A DNS Record".

[Here](https://www.hosting.co.uk/blog/how-to-point-domain-to-ip-in-9-steps/) is a good article on what you would need to do.